# How NOT to display cURL response data in php?

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I have the following code that makes an API call to a URL.  The response is in `json` format.
When the response data is received, I want to further process the data using another function and **NOT** display the data in the console (I want to display only the final processed output). But currently, the response from the API call is being displayed in the console along with the final processed output.

The processed final data will be saved in `$processedData` variable.

```
<?php

function getDataFromApi(){
    $url = 'https://www.myurl.com/data.json';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

function processData($data){
    /**
     * Do the processing and save processed data in $processedData variable.
     */

    // Finally display the data
    echo $processedData;
}

$result = getDataFromApi();
processData($result);
```

How do I **NOT** display the intermediate cURL resplonse but only the final response?

Answer (score 4):

you are passing data variable but echoing the process data variable

```
function getDataFromApi(){
   $url = 'https://www.myurl.com/data.json';
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   $processdata = processData($data);
   return $processdata;
}


function processData($data){
  /**
   * Do the processing
   */

  // Finally display the data
  echo $data;
}
echo $getDataFromApi();
```

Comment: The processed final data will be saved in $processedData variable.
I have made edit to the question.
But still, the initial (unprocessed) response is being displayed in the console. This solution does not do anything to that !

Comment: okay you mean you are making some changes with the data and the n display the process data ?

Comment: Yes exactly. Display **only** the processed data, **NOT** the original data.

Comment: see updated answer please I think you need to do like this. as currently you are calling both function at same time.

Comment: If problem is solved could you please mark this as answer

Answer (score 3):

I found answer to my question myself so I am posting it here so that it can help others.

My code as stated in the question, by default executes the curl request and prints the output in the screen.

In the current form, the line `$result = curl_exec($ch);` will execute the cURL request and returns `true` or `false` based on whether the request was successful or not. So, the `$result` variable will **NOT** hold the response data (as opposed to what I *assumed* earlier), but either `true` or `false`.

In order *not* to display the response and save it in a variable (and pass it to another function), **`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`** option needs to be set to `true` as follows:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`

This line instructs cURL to Return the response as a string instead of outputting it to the screen.

The final code would be as follows:

```
<?php

function getDataFromApi(){
    $url = 'https://www.myurl.com/data.json';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

function processData($data){
    /**
     * Do the processing and save processed data in $processedData variable.
     */

    // Finally display the data
    echo $processedData;
}

$result = getDataFromApi();
processData($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below

```
function processData($data){
  /** * Do the processing */ 
  // Finally display the data echo $data; 
}
```

Comment: Add $data instead of $processedData variable.